# Dynamically find position to show / fade the backtop

Tags: jquery

```
 $('.des-sidebar').sticky({
         topSpacing: 0, // Space between element and top of the viewport
         zIndex: 100, // z-index
         stopper: ".ftr-container" // Id, class, or number value
     });    

_sidebarTool.css('position', function(index, state){

    if(state == 'fixed'){
        console.log('down');
        TweenLite.to( $('.backtop'), 0.5, { autoAlpha: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut });
    }

 if ( state == 'static') {
        TweenLite.to( $('.backtop'), 0.5, { autoAlpha: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut });
        console.log('up');
    }


});
```

Currently using the sticky sidebar from https://github.com/AndrewHenderson/jSticky. When scroll up and down, it will add inline styles for position: fixed and static. I want to check for inline style to display / fade backtop (.backtop class). Right now, it is not showing backtop when scrolling down.

I am not sure if I miss something. Help appreciated!

**Update**
Saw on console.log that 0, static, up is there when scrolling up and down. It is not correct as it should show up when scroll up and it should show down when scroll down.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Are your `console.log` statements firing?

Comment: @helion3 - it is not firing anything :( i thought _sidebarTool.css(...){} might be wrong way to display/fade backtop dynamically on css change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code should work, It's not about the paramater naming, but I think you should execute and check for changes on window `scroll()` also.

Please check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yv54z/

Comment: but i am using plugin so how to check for changes on window scroll()?

Comment: but i am using plugin so how to check for changes on window scroll()? I also try window.scroll(){...css if/else} but it displays two "back to top"..also how to check for bottom to stop sidebar from overlapping footer?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but have you viewed the demo? The idea is to check for the position property value of the sidebar, right? On your original code I believe it's on checking once so you put it inside the `scroll()` event to check everytime the user scrolls.

Comment: for the footer overlapping the plugin has a `stopper` option, I'm not sure what exactly it does but maybe you can try setting `stopper:'footer'`.

Comment: thanks I already got it working yst, and thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value), the `css` method takes a second argument function as you have, but the arguments are `function(index, value)`. You likely want the second.

Comment: According to said docs: `index position of the element in the set`

Comment: trying to understand index and value. :-/ thanks though

Comment: Just throw a `console.log(index, value)` into your function and see what it prints in your case

Comment: threw console.log(index, state) and i got [0 "static"] and also saw "up"-- it is not right. scrolling up and down still static and up strange.